# equidistribution theorem in complex dynamics for rational maps

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, dynamical-systems

I'm studying equidistribution in dynamical system which is due to Brolin(1965, page140 for polynomials) https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.afm/1485893514 and Freire, Lopes, and Mane (1983,
Theorem page 46 for rational maps)[http://mat.ufrgs.br/~alopes/aninvariant.pdf](http://mat.ufrgs.br/%7Ealopes/aninvariant.pdf)

I'm curious that why do we exclude exceptional points in order to make probabilility measure  of point mass distribution $\mu_n$  converge weakly (in a weak-* topological sense) ? I.e.,
$$\mu_n(a)=\frac{1}{d^n}\sum_{i=0}^{d^n}\delta_{z^{(n)}_i(a)}\rightarrow \mu_f$$ where $a\in \text{Exc}(f)^c$ (the complement of exceptional set of $f$) and $\mu_f$ probability measure with respect to a rational map $f$.

I'm try to convince myself but did not come with any intuitively reason.

I further have question in connection with the $\mathbf{maximal\, entropy \,with \,respect\, to\, rational\, maps}$. Is there a simple explanation for this term or example?

Answer (score 1):

By definition if $z$ is exceptional then its grand orbit is finite, then you can see that the $\mu_n$ defined as above would converge to a measure supported in the grand orbit of $z$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, which is a finite and discrete set. So I hope now it make sense to you to exclude such points, although the previous argument does not explain the convergence for non-exceptional points.

Now, if you look for the measure entropy definition in some dynamical systems book, you'll be able to see that if $f$ is a rational function and $\mu$ is an $f$-invariant measure then $h(f,\mu) \leq \deg(f)$. However, it turns out that $h(f,\mu_f)=\deg(f)$, precisely. Here $\deg$ denotes the degree of $f$ as a rational function. Then $\mu_f$ is known as the maximum entropy measure.